# .xsd schema is not recognized as a class in my solution

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am updating a web service that was written in the early 2010s with no documentation that integrates with a serial number and barcode printing SDK.  Part of the App_Code Data Access Layer is a .xsd file that contains all the information for a class.  However, the rest of the code isn't seeing this as a usable type or class.  Is there something I need to do to get visual studio to see what's in the XML?

I've tried using VS dev tools to compile the .xsd file into a .cs, but it's still not being picked up.  I looked through the other posts about .xsd files on here but none matched exactly what I was looking for.

There is a line at the top of the XML that lays out the name, which is referenced in the rest of the code, but that namespace is not recognized anywhere.

Ideally, the rest of the solution would see it as a usable class to run instances of.

Comment: Assuming it's some kind of a Microsoft web service, the existing web service should expose its WSDL when accessing it via https://webserviceurl?WSDL. That being the case you can save the content to a .wsdl file (and any related .xsd files) to be parsed by the [wsdl.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/7h3ystb6(v=vs.95)) tool.